# Evaluation of the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}x-\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, proof-verification

I'm trying to evaluate the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}x-\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}$

> Since there is a square root of a product namely $\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}$ I
>   think it's useful to use $\text{GM}\le\text{AM}$ for $(x-a)$ & $(x-b)$:
>   $\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}\le\dfrac{(x-a)+(x-b)}{2}=x-\dfrac{a+b}{2}\tag*{}$
>
> To see whether the function $f(x)=x-\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}$ is increasing
>   or decreasing,
>
> \begin{align}f'(x)&=1-\dfrac{2x-(a+b)}{2\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}}\\&=1-\dfrac{\dfrac{x-(a+b)}2}{\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}}\\&=1-\dfrac{\text{AM}}{GM}\\&\le0
>  \because\text{ GM}\le\text{AM}\end{align}
>
> hence $f(x)=x-\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}$ is decreasing. Then in order for the
>   existence of the limit, $f(x)$ must be bounded below.
>
> Here I again use the same inequality:
>
> \begin{align}\\&\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}\le\dfrac{(x-a)+(x-b)}{2}=x-\dfrac{a+b}{2}\\&\implies
>  f(x)=x-\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}\ge\dfrac{a+b}{2}\end{align}
>
> If I'm right, then the limit exists and
>   $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}x-\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}=\dfrac{a+b}2$

Another query is that in the inequality $\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}\le\dfrac{(x-a)+(x-b)}{2}$ the equality holds iff $x-a=x-b$- how to solve it for $x$? I want to know where $f(x)$ takes its minimum.

Comment: It's worth noting that your AM/GM argument, while very nice and well presented, only proves that the limit exists and is *greater than or equal* to $(a+b)/2$. Something more is required to show that it's actually *equal* to $(a+b)/2$.

Comment: @ Barry Cipra can you please suggest edits to my answer?

Comment: I was just about to add that I'd actually like to see your argument completed, because nothing obvious comes to (my) mind that doesn't effectively replace the entire proof with the approach given in Robert Z's answer. It's worth thinking about!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, but the limit is easier to evaluate if you consider
$$x-\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}=\frac{x^2-(x-a)(x-b)}{x+\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}}=
\frac{(a+b)-ab/x}{1+\sqrt{(1-a/x)(1-b/x)}}$$
for $x> \max(a,b,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, do the change of variable $x = 1/t$
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}x - \sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)} = \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - (a + b)t + abt^2}}t$$
and apply Taylor:
$$\sqrt{1 - (a + b)t + abt^2} = 1 - \frac{a + b}2 t + \cdots$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

[Evaluation of the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}x-\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062724/evaluation-of-the-limit-displaystyle-lim-x-to-inftyx-sqrtx-ax-b/3062811#3062811),

Rationalizing the numerator, 
$$\lim_{t\to0^+}\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-(a+b)t+abt^2}}t=\lim_{t\to0^+}\dfrac{1-(1-(a+b)t+abt^2)}t\cdot\lim_{t\to0^+}\dfrac1{1+\sqrt{1-(a+b)t+abt^2}}$$

As $t\to0,t\ne0,\dfrac{1-(1-(a+b)t+abt^2)}t=(a+b)-abt$